# Error ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers

Is it possible to have multiple tables in one TRIGGER? Let say I have Employee, Skill and Customer Tables and I have Eventlogs table to capture the audit. I tried to add Skill_T but I got ORA-04079 error. Any correction? Thank you!

NOTE: I am using Oracle SQL Developer Oracle11gEE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_REC
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE_T, SKILL_T
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_LOGID NUMBER;
    V_USER  VARCHAR(30);
    V_DATE  VARCHAR(30);

BEGIN
  SELECT EVENTLOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, USER, SYSDATE INTO V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, 'INSERT');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, 'DELETE');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, 'UPDATE');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DML Trigger is associated (tied to) with only ONE table.  It executes when DML is submitted against that table only.
See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888

Comment: Thank you Hemant. I will now then create one trigger per table.